# message box for empty row in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

i have large excel with many rows which can increase in future ,so i want to identufy the way if on button click i can check if any field is empty , i tried below macros with checking cell value and its working but how to select all columns and their cells to check empty value

```
Sub ProcFile()
Dim wsRaw As Worksheet: Set wsRaw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Shell2")

Dim iRow, x, LRow, sRow, col As Long

LRow = getLastRow(wsRaw, "A")

If wsRaw.Range("A6").Value = "" Then MsgBox "Raw Data tab is Empty!!", vbCritical: Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapt the code below. It gets the last non-blank cells in row 1 (assuming the contents of the row are headers). This allows to get the last column. Then loop through each column and row (if necessary).

```
Sub Loop_Column_Row()
    
    Dim lRow, lCol As Long
    
    'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
    'This assumes that the first row has column headers
    lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    'Loop through columns
    For x = 1 To lCol
        'Find the last non-blank cell in the column
        lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, x).End(xlUp).Row
    
        'Loop through rows
        'Start from row 2 as row 1 is the row with headers
        For y = 2 To lRow
            If Cells(y, x) = "" Then
                'Display message box when empty cell is found
                MsgBox "Cell in Row: " & y & " Column: " & x & " is empty"
                'Stop executing the method when 1st empty cell found
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
  
End Sub
```